# Is it possible to reference outter class pointer from nested class?

Tags: java, this

I need to use `this` pointer from the outer class in the inner class.

I don't know how to do it without saving the `this` pointer. Is there an alternative?

```
class outerclass {

  outerClass thisPointer;

  outerclass () {
      //
      // NOTE: I am saving this pointer here to reference
      // by the inner class later.   I am trying to find
      // a different alternative instead of saving this pointer.
      //
      thisPointer = this; 
  }

  class innerClass {

      void doSomething () {

           //
           // is there a way to reference the outter class
           // without having to save the thisPointer from
           // the outter class.
           // NOTE someObject is a class outside of the
           // outterclass control.
           //
           someObject.someMethod (thisPointer);
      }
  }     
}
```

Comment: Java has references not pointers. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the syntax `NameOfOuterClass.this`:

```
void doSomething () {
    someObject.someMethod(outerClass.this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
outclass.this
```

should do the trick.

I am assuming that your outer class name is outerclass. By convention in Java you should start class names with a capital letter

In case I havent understood your example properly then here is some sample code. Here the value of a in the outer class (Test1) is being assigned to a local variable in the inner class (Test2)

```
public class Test1  {

    private int a =42;         

    private class Test2 {

         public void a() {
             int i = Test1.this.a;
         }
}
```